# Adding attribute to rails model object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model **students**. in *studentsController* I select a collection of students. I want to attach a flag to the first and the last record.

I'll display the list of students with a partial like this: **students/_student** and when a user clicks each student, they'll get a popup.

I want to use the flag to determine whether this student is the first/last so that I can add a query parameter to the url. So for instance, the url will look like this when you hover over the first student: **localhost:3000/student/1?location=first**

When displaying though a partial, the collection is not present in the partial, and so I cannot just do a test like this: student.first?

Any ideas? Thank you.

[EDIT]. This was originally a reply to @neils, but I figured I'd put it out there:
It works however I have another issue. Because I'm using an "auto-scroll" feature, which loads in more students as the user scrolls down the page ( 3 at a time), the "first" and "last" gets added to the first and third student of each row rather than the actual first and last of the collection. The way I do the auto-scroll: I use $.getScript to request the **index.js.erb** file. That file renders the **students/_student** like so: *render @students*, and attach to a container div. I render the url in that template (**students/_student**), so the params gets rendered every first/third time.

Comment: why don't you use params[:location] as you are passing it in url??

Comment: Please add some code so that its easy to solve the problem.

Comment: @Sush I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I will use params[:location] to get it back and figure out whether it's the first or last item. My problem is attaching the location params to the url in the first place. I need to figure when to attach it, and so I need to know which item is the first and which one is the last.

Comment: @soundar I'm at the day job right now, so I can't paste in any code until later on. Is there something specific you want me to explain? Thanks for your response.

Comment: ok.Are you rendering the students like render "student", :collection => @students ?

Comment: @soundar I'm doing it like this: render @students; this way each student is rendered by the partial in students/_student without an explicit loop. Check this out: http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/61-simplify-render-in-views . Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can proceed with your `render @students` call if you want. Just take note that you magically have a `student_counter` helper available for you in your partial when you do that. Now in your partial, you can compare the `student_counter` with `@students.size` and set your `link_to`'s `:location=>'first/last'` via helper or decorator.

Comment: I will definitely try this out. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you already assign some collection of students to @students (`Student.all`, `Student.where(some_conditions)`, whatever...) in your controller, you could do the following:

Add `attr_accessor :flag` to your `Student` model:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :flag
  #... rest of your code
end
```

This creates an non-ActiveRecord attribute on you Student instances.

Than you could do something in the controller like:

```
@students[0].flag = 'first'
@students[-1].flag = 'last'
```

and then use that info in your view. Not really elegant, but it should do the trick.

**EDIT:**  Elaborated the above a bit, to make it more clear. 
**EDIT2:**  Fixed mistake, `attr_accessor` is the right method, not `attr_accessable`...

Comment: niels what you think @students[0] contents?

Comment: Well, it's elegant enough. Thanks @neils!

Comment: Just checked this out, but this wouldn't work. There's no **flag** method on @students.

Comment: @berto77, you would have to create an attribute for `flag`. You can't just assign it on the fly.

Comment: After a moment of consideration, I think my solution, although it should work, violates some best practices: it introduces view logic in the model and in the controller. So, use at your own risk! :)

Comment: neils! thank you. I did exactly this. It worked, however I have another issue when I do this. Because I'm using an "auto-scroll" feature, which loads in more students as the user scrolls down the page ( 3 at a time), the "first" and "last" gets added to the first and third student of each row rather than the actual first and last. The way I do the auto-scroll: I use $.getScript to request the **index.js.erb** file. That file renders the **students/_student** like so: _render @students_. I render the url in that template, so the params gets rendered every first/third time. Any ideas?

Comment: hmm, that complicates things. Probably better to move everything over to javascript. I don't normally do a lot of js, but it should be not to difficult to do this in jQuery, after each autoload to first reset this flag (however you set it), and than add it with the `first()` and `last()` method. This also cleans up your controller!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but I'm going to take a shot at it.

Assuming you're using `@students` as the instance variable for your list, you can pass the list of students to your partial like so:

```
<%= render 'students', :locals => {:students => @students} %>
```

Inside the `students/_students`, you can loop through the list and determine their position by using `each_with_index`:

```
<% students.each_with_index do |student, index| %>
```

Comment: Hi @Terence thanks for your answer. I'm trying to avoid doing a loop in my views. I'm trying to use the best practice like so: render :@students where the actual partial that gets rendered is students/_student for each record in @students; without the obvious loop. See here: http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/61-simplify-render-in-views

Comment: @berto77, you said in your question that you want the collection to be  present in your partial, but you're trying to avoid doing a loop in your views? Those two statements are contradictory to each other. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Also, the point of doing `render 'students', :locals => {:students => @students}` (which isn't necessarily bad practice according to your link) instead of `render @students` is to use `each_with_index`. Doing the second option will only result to using `each`.

Comment: you can proceed with your 'render @students" call if you want. just take note that you magically have a student_counter helper available for you in your partial when you do that. now in your partial, you can compare the student_counter with @students.size and set your link_to's :location=>'first/last' via helper or decorator

Comment: I wasn't aware of that helper. Thanks. TIL. You should probably post that as an answer.

Comment: @keikun17 Thanks! This makes total sense. I'll try it out after 5 p.m :)